# Checking if a user is the author

Tags: python, django, web

It seems logic that any author of an article, can delete his own post. But I don't really know how to check if a user is the current author of a post.
Here is my code :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Details | {{article.title}} {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="starter-template" style="text-align: center; margin: 2% 0">
        <h1>{{object.title.capitalize}}</h1>
        <p>{{object.body}}</p>
        <p style="font-style: italic">{{object.author}}</p>
        <p>{{object.date}}</p>
        {% if object.author == user.username %}
        <p>
            <a href="{% url 'delete_post' object.pk %}">Delete</a>
            <a href="{% url 'edit_post' object.pk%}"> Edit</a>
        </p>
        {% endif %}

    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

"object.author == user.username " is returning False. Why is that ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Show your model. What is the author field pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

You can check like below. Please add your models to view relations.

```
{% object.author.user == user %}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{% if object.author == user %}
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering with code-only. Note that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers of the question. Thus, please edit the post to contain an explanation as to why this line of code works.